# Adding libraries to google app engine php

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, wkhtmltopdf

I am using GAE for a Laravel application. I use `WKHTMLTOPDF` to create PDFs. For my local deployment i use a php-fpm docker container and i have to install a few libraries to make it work.

```
# Install all dependencies
apt-get update -yqq && \
apt-get install -y \
libxrender1 \
libfontconfig1 \
libjpeg62 \
libxtst6 \
libssl1.0-dev \
wget \
&& wget https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/blob/master/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64?raw=true -O /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \
```

How do i add these libraries to my GAE deployment?

Comment: did you ever found how to add WKHTMLTOPDF?

Comment: Hey.. there is no way to do it in the php environment. You can create your own image and add it there. Like it says in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) you have an example on how to deploy an application with a Dockerfile to App Engine Flex on a custom runtime. For more information on how to build custom runtimes, check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).